# FileSystemNotFoundException FileSystems.getFileSystem

Tags: java, nio

FileSystems.getFileSystem throws FileSystemNotFoundException at line ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171

What should i do to overcome that ?
Thanks in advance...

```
public void copy(File sourceFile){
Path zipfile = Paths.get(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipfile.toUri());
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(uri);
Path nf = fs.getPath("new.txt");
.....    

}
```

Comment: that was realated to classloader and nio. but my scenario is i got a existing a zip file in a given directory and add a file inside it, during that throws given exception.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) the correct uri prefix is `jar:file:`

Comment: it has already got that prefix.the value of uri was jar:file///C:/Users/fk/Desktop/mmi.zip

Comment: is it `jar:file//...` or `jar:file://...`

Comment: sorry for typo. it was jar:file:///... .

Comment: perhaps you are not allowed the open the zip file as a jar? have you tried to rename to mmi.jar ?

Comment: actually not, i'll try now.

Comment: same exception again. i tried URI uri = new URI("jar", path.toUri().toString(),null); but it is still same